# Representing homotopy classes of Kähler manifolds by harmonic maps

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, non-positive-curvature

Let $(M,g_M)$ be a compact Kähler manifold with negative bisectional curvature. Let $\alpha : (S,g_S) \to M$ be a continuous map from a compact Riemannian manifold $(S,g_S)$.

> Is $\alpha$ homotopic to a harmonic map?

If $g_M$ has non-positive sectional curvature, then this follows from the well-known result of Eells--Sampson. My question concerns whether the sectional curvature can be replaced with the bisectional curvature.

I know that Jost-Yau and many others have studied harmonic maps in Kähler geometry, but I can't find a specific answer to the above question. Thanks in advance.